# How to add tags depending on the length of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code below. I need to add a `<li>` tag inside the `<ul>` of the `carousel-controls` for each image, since the number of images can vary, I need to do it with js, but not sure what to do after I get the length of `image-controller`

```
var img_number = $(".image-container img").length;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='image-container'>
  <img src="/img.png" alt="xga-1">
  <img src="/img2.png" alt="xga-1">
  <img src="/img3.png" alt="xga-1">
</div>

<div class="carousel-controls">
   <p class="angle-left" data-icon='ei-chevron-left' data-size='m'></p>
   <ul>
      <!-- Insert a <li>  for each image -->
    </ul>
   <p class="angle-right" data-icon='ei-chevron-right' data-size='m'></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: have you looked at `Array.forEach` or a simple `for` loop? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do anything with the length of the images you found, you can just loop over them and append them to the `UL` element, wrapped with a new `li` element:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".image-container img").each((i, el) => {
    $('ul').append($("<li>").append(el));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='image-container'>
  <img src="/img.png" alt="xga-1">
  <img src="/img2.png" alt="xga-1">
  <img src="/img3.png" alt="xga-1">
</div>

<div class="carousel-controls">
   <p class="angle-left" data-icon='ei-chevron-left' data-size='m'></p>
   <ul>
      <!-- Insert a <li>  for each image -->
    </ul>
   <p class="angle-right" data-icon='ei-chevron-right' data-size='m'></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: btw, I saw your propose for edit, but the links are for DOM append, and not for jquery's (which is what I used in the code above)

Comment: You are in truth. Thanks for your fell back.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can add them

```
$(".image-container img").each(function(){
$("ul").append("<li>"+$(this).html()+"</li>")
}
);
```